# Spring MVC URI mapping configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I use WebApplicationInitializer to initialize Spring Dispatcher, this is how it was set.

```
public class MyApplicationInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer{

@Override
public void onStartup(final ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    final XmlWebApplicationContext appconfig = new XmlWebApplicationContext();
    appconfig.setConfigLocation("/WEB-INF/app-servlet.xml");

    final ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher =
            servletContext.addServlet("my_app", new DispatcherServlet(appconfig));
    dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    dispatcher.addMapping("/app/*.do");
    System.out.println("Here I am ");
}
```

and I intention is to use controller class as namespace as

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("app")
public class TestingController{

    @RequestMapping("/{act}.do")
    public ModelAndView getIndex(){ return new ModelAndView("/index.jsp"); }
}
```

it seems reasonable, but when I try to run this artifact from tomcat I got this error message.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid <url-pattern> /app/*.do in servlet mapping
```

Question is why i can't define dispatching URI like this and if I want to achieve class URI + method URI for a dispatcher how should I set it?

Comment: dispatcher.addMapping("*.do"); may resolve the issue

Comment: @sudeepcv, I knew "*.do" will do the job properly, I am wondering if I can apply different namespace like "/my_app/*.do" and "your_app/*.do" so I can indeed using two controllers respectively for different requests?

Comment: Separate your controllers, Your `dispatcher.addMapping("*.do");` as it is same, Not to worry about different controller requestMapping. Mention your requestMapping to which controller you want to map it.. Just Change your RequestMapping(value="/1stController/my_app.do" or "/2ndController/your_app.do"), like this, This will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your endpoints are formulated for struts. Spring does not support this. Probably because it is a non-standard REST technique.

The more RESTful way of doing this would be to design the URI like this:

```
 /app/do/{action}
```

Or:

```
/app/do?action={action}
```

However, you can use regex PathVariables like this:

```
/app/{action:[A-Za-z\\d]+}.do
```

Then, within the method block evaluate the request path and redirect to different controllers conditionally based on pattern matching. 
Here is the example I was able to get working:

```java
package com.app.controller;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;


@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/test")
public class TestController
{

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{action:[A-Za-z\\d]+}.do")
    public @ResponseBody
    ModelAndView getDo(@PathVariable String action)
    {
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/test/action/" + action);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/action/a")
    public @ResponseBody
    ModelAndView getAction()
    {
        return new ModelAndView("/index.jsp");
    }

}
```

The `getAction` method could be in another controller if you wanted it to, but by using **regex** and **redirect** I think you can accomplish what you are trying to do.